# Nominatim docker-compose behind jwilders's nginx-proxy

Tags: docker-compose, nominatim, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm trying to setup a Nominatim instance as docker-compose stack (https://github.com/mediagis/nominatim-docker/blob/master/4.2/contrib/docker-compose.yml) behind a nginx reverse proxy provided by jwilder (https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy).

Currently the Nominatim instance is up and runing and can be reached on the server via exposed port.

The problem arises now when I'm trying to connect to the instance via the nginx-proxy provided url... it simply fails, with Erorr 404.

My docker-compose file looks like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
    nominatim:
        container_name: nominatim
        image: mediagis/nominatim:4.2
        deploy:
          resources:
            limits:
              cpus: '4.0'
              memory: 10G
            reservations:
              cpus: '3.0'
              memory: 8G
        restart: always
        networks:
          - bridge-all
        ports:
            - "8085:8080" # Do not change the second port, only the first before the colon
        environment:
            PBF_URL: https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/dach-latest.osm.pbf
            REPLICATION_URL: https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/dach-updates/
            UPDATE_MODE: continuous
            NOMINATIM_PASSWORD: TOP-SECRET
            
            IMPORT_STYLE: address
            IMPORT_WIKIPEDIA: "true"
            IMPORT_US_POSTCODES: "false"
            IMPORT_GB_POSTCODES: "false"
            
            THREADS: 4
            
            POSTGRES_SHARED_BUFFERS: 1GB
            POSTGRES_MAINTENANCE_WORK_MEM: 4GB
            POSTGRES_AUTOVACUUM_WORK_MEM: 1GB
            POSTGRES_WORK_MEM: 50MB
            POSTGRES_EFFECTIVE_CACHE_SIZE: 4GB
            POSTGRES_SYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT: "false"
            POSTGRES_MAX_WAL_SIZE: 1GB
            POSTGRES_CHECKPOINT_TIMEOUT: 10min
            POSTGRES_CHECKPOINT_COMPLETION_TARGET: 0.9
            
            TZ: Europe/Berlin
            VIRTUAL_HOST: nominatim.mydomain.de
            VIRTUAL_PORT: 8085
            #VIRTUAL_PROTO: fastcgi
            #VIRTUAL_ROOT: /srv/nominatim-project/website
            #LETSENCRYPT_HOST: nominatim.mydomain.de
            
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: /mnt/nominatim/db
              target: /var/lib/postgresql/14/main
            - type: bind
              source: /mnt/nominatim/flatnode
              target: /nominatim/flatnode
        shm_size: 5gb
        
networks:
  bridge-all:
        external: true
```

I hope someone has any idea where the problem comes from.
As you may see i already tried around with some of the options but didn't got the proxy to work.